# How to remove gap from top ? HIGHCHARTS

Tags: highcharts

please help.

How do I remove these gaps?

I would like charts he has been setting up from the beginning, and now he has some distance from the top.

it's my code, unfortunately I don't know what to do to make the chart visible ...

```
   [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/kmartynak/mseh2znt/1/
```

[image]

Comment: I reproduced your code: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6b94a287/ are you sure that it is complete? Does it miss the CSS config or something?

Comment: I have also styled in css ... probably because of it.
Thank you very much! but as I see it, this is the problem ... the chart has padding / distance from the top that I can't have anyway: /

Comment: Notice that you set fixed tickPosition which has an impact on the chart rendering: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zL2y4nx0/

Comment: I have to have it because the chart is normally too big

Comment: but it doesn't change the chart height - just decrease yAxis render size. I set the yAxis.max as 100, is this a soltuion that you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8f7tgxpq/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max

Comment: I gave a negative value and it works. marginTop: -50. thank you